How to evaluate this multivariable integral using the prescription of contour integral around branch cuts?
I am trying to show that:
\begin{align*}I&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathrm{d} x \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathrm{d} y\{\mathrm{i} +(x-y)\}^{-a}(\mathrm{i} + y)^{-b}(\mathrm{i} - x)^{-c} \\
&= \mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i} \pi a / 2}\left(\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} \pi b / 2}-\mathrm{e}^{-3 \mathrm{i} \pi b / 2}\right)\left(\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} \pi c / 2}-\mathrm{e}^{-3 \mathrm{i} \pi c / 2}\right) \int_{0}^{\infty} \mathrm{d} x \int_{0}^{\infty} \mathrm{d} y(x+y+3)^{-a} y^{-b} x^{-c}\\
& = 4\pi^2\frac{\Gamma(a+b+c-2)}{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)\Gamma(c)}3^{-(a+b+c-2)}e^{-\frac{i\pi}{2}(a+b+c-2)} \end{align*}
where, $a,b,c\in\mathbb{C}$.
I realize that in each $x$ and $y$ complex planes, there exist 2 branch points. But I am having difficulty in how to close the contours to get to the 2nd line.
